# trying to implement quick sort and use insertion sort when the listsize is <= 10. getting incorrect returns

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

```
import java.util.Comparator;


public class SortedList implements Container{
private int size;
private int front = 0;
private int rear = 0;
private WorkOrder[] buffer;
Comparator comparator;

public SortedList(){
    buffer = new WorkOrder[10];
}
/**
 * The comparator that the container will use to arrange the container
 * 
 * @param comp
 */
public void setComparator(Comparator comp){
    if (comp == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    comparator = comp;
}

/**
 * Add a workorder to the container
 */
public void add(WorkOrder wo){
    if(wo == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (size == capacity()){
        WorkOrder[] regrowArray = new WorkOrder[2*capacity()];
        for (int i = 0; i<size;i++){
            regrowArray[i] = buffer[i];
        }
        buffer = regrowArray;
        rear = size;
    }

    buffer[rear] = wo;
    rear++;
    size++;
}

/**
 * Gets a workorder (removes it also) from the container
 */
public WorkOrder getNext(){
    if (isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }
    WorkOrder itemRemoved = buffer[front];
    buffer[front] = null;
    front++;
    size--;

    return itemRemoved;
}

/**
 * Arranges the workorders in the required order
 * Uses the comparator if necessary
 * Some data structures may not need this method (like Queue)
 * Just make it a no-op for those structures.
 */
public void arrange(){
    if (buffer == null || size == 0){
        return;
    }
    partition(0,size-1);
    //sort(0,size-1);
}

private void partition(int left, int right){
    int pivotIndex = (right + left) / 2;
    int i = left;
    int j = right;

    if ((right-left) <= 10){
        insertionSort(left,right);
        return;
    }
    while (i <= j){
        while (comparator.compare(buffer[i],buffer[pivotIndex]) < 0){
            i++;
        }
        while (comparator.compare(buffer[j],buffer[pivotIndex]) > 0){
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j){
            swap(i,j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (left < j){
        partition(left,j);
    }
    if (i<right){
        partition(i, right);
    }
}

private void insertionSort(int left, int right){
    for (int i = 1; i < right; i++){
        WorkOrder val = buffer[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j>=0 && comparator.compare(buffer[j], val) > 0){
            buffer[j+1] = buffer[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        buffer[j+1] = val;
    }
}

private void swap(int x, int y){
    WorkOrder temp = buffer[x];
    buffer[x] = buffer[y];
    buffer[y] = temp;
}
}
```

the output I see is:
0123567894

The comparator being passed in is dependent on the junits being run on it so that is why I am using comparator. compare for everything. I'm almost positive the sorting algos are correct, I could be manipulating the backing array incorrectly.

Comment: it passes in an Object with a slated number of hours that it compares. there is a loop setup to pass in Work Orders 10 times. it looks like WO1 - 1 hour, WO2 - 2 hour, WO3 - 3 hour, etc.

Comment: im asking cause maybe the `size - 1` passed to the partition method is omitting the last number? making a partition from 0 to the second to last number instead of the last one.

Comment: when i change the index to just size, it fixes the 10 element sorting but causes a nullpointerexception when i pass in larger tests. i had used size-1 to index from 0 to the last element since size is how many elements are in the array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems its the `insertion sort` part:

```
for (int i = 1; i < right; i++){ //going from 1 to one previous to the last (right - 1)
    WorkOrder val = buffer[i];
    int j = i - 1;
    while (j>=0 && comparator.compare(buffer[j], val) > 0){
        buffer[j+1] = buffer[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }
    buffer[j+1] = val;
}
```

you need to take into account that it needs to loop until the last one, since you know that the `right` variable is the last index of that partition.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= right; i++) //replace < for <=
```

since right is the last index (and it needs to be taken into account) of the array when its 10 or less elements.

`edit:`

The only thing else i see (in the `quick sort` code) is this part:

```
if (left < j){ 
    partition(left,j); //trying to partition from left to j (since 'j' and 'i' may overlap)
}
```

it should be

```
if (left < (i - 1)){ 
    partition(left,i - 1); //so the partition doesnt overlap with the 'i' to 'right' partition by an element (since i and j may overlap at the end).
}
```

That way you ensure that you are splitting the partition in half at all times.

Comment: Perfect, you nailed why insertion was failing to grab the final one. For my quick sort however i still get this output off where the first ten items get dispersed across every 10 items so A20 is preceded by A2 and A30 is preceded by A3 etc. Thank you so much for the help man.

Comment: glad i could help a little bit, i did an edit to see if it helps you a little more.

Comment: it didn't seem to fix the bug, when i remove the insertion sort call in partition the ordering goes down the drain but i don't know what is wrong with the quick sorting i implemented.

Comment: Edward, after more hours i realized the test was looking at the string comparison, in which case that "bug" was the correct output. i thought i passed in an hours comparison. thanks for the help, it was just me berating my computer for giving me a correct output!